# HD 3000 is not detected

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 which is runing on an Intel i7 based laptop with a gt540m nVidia graphic card.

The problem is that the HD 3000 is not beeing used and lots of battery is being consumed , showing backup of 1.5 hour instead of 5 hours.

Comment: See this http://askubuntu.com/a/156120/35775